# Is there any cleaner or more efficient way to achieve what my code is performing?

Tags: java, string, string-comparison

I am trying to create a boolean that compares two Strings, and gets the percentage of characters that are a match in the two Strings specified. If the percentage is more than or equal to 80, return true. What I have so far works, but it feels kind of cheap-hacky, and I was wondering if there was a better way to do it. Here is what I have:

```
    public static boolean isMatch(String word, String comparison) {
    int matches = 0;
    char[] word_characters = word.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    char[] comparison_characters = comparison.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    int minLength = Math.min(word_characters.length, comparison_characters.length);
    int highest = (word_characters.length > comparison_characters.length ? word_characters.length : comparison_characters.length);
    for(int i = 0; i < minLength; i++) {
        if (word_characters[i] == comparison_characters[i]) {
            matches++;    
        }
    }
    int percent = (int) (matches * 100.0f) / highest;
    return percent >= 80;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is this method to be used for? Although the code could be cleaned up a little bit... I'm more concerned about why it returns a boolean instead of how much the words match. What if you enter "The" and "Tha" ? You'll wind up with a 66% match and get a value of false.

Comment: The only improvements I would suggest are style: fix the local variable names and overly long lines (for this medium).  (And I'm not sure that this is a useful test if you are trying to look for differences in natural language texts.)

Comment: @AnthonyAudette It's used in a game. Game has a text-based command system, one of the commands is "spawn". The aim of the command is to spawn a certain item in the game. 

For example: spawn itemnamehere

There are tens of thousands of items, so I use it to see if the item name matches the input by 80% (it's mostly just used to make it a little faster if we don't remember the exact name of an item)

Comment: Consider "hamburger" versus "hammburger".  I suggest that you read about Levenshtein distance and similar metrics - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Comment: Ah ok, well if it's a dev command you probably don't need to give yourself that much of a headache optimizing this method by a few fractions of a millisecond.

Comment: Apache commons StringUtils has a `getLevenshteinDistance` method.  This is exactly what it's for.

Comment: Thanks guys. I've looked into Levenshtein Distance. Turns out this will work very well for what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: just curious, why there is a ternary there. The way `Math.min` is used, similarly `Math.max` could have been used. Any particular reason for this?